# Error in Xcode compiler for function template for mersenne twist random generator

Tags: c++, xcode, templates

I'm trying to implement a thread-safe random number generator using an answer to a different post on this site. Xcode gives me a compile error in some system-provided source code. I've cut all the cruft out and this is the minimum code that will reproduce the error on the latest up-to-date Xcode.

```
#include <random>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;

mt19937 * _generator = NULL;

template <typename T> T ts_rand(void)
{
    uniform_int_distribution<T> distribution(0, INT_MAX);
    static bool fInited = false;
    if (!fInited)
    {
        _generator = new mt19937();
        fInited = true;
    }
    return distribution(_generator);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int random_number = ts_rand<int>();
    return random_number;
}
```

When I try to compile it, I get an error in the file 'algorithm', lines 2843 and 2865: "Semantic issue Type 'std::__1::mersenne_twister_engine * cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no members".

If I change _generator to be an actual instance instead of a pointer, it compiles fine. So that makes me think that there is something about this use of a templating that I don't understand, rather than an error in a system-provided file. FWIW, this same construct compiles and runs fine on VS 2013.

StackOverflow's suggested similar questions would seem to indicate that this might be related to VS' generous interpretations of incompletely-defined template classes, but I'm at a loss.

Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your `_generator` is a pointer, but [`uniform_int_distribution::operator()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution/operator%28%29) expects a reference to a `UniformRandomNumberGenerator`.

You just need to do:

```
return distribution(*_generator);
```

Comment: Barry - thanks! I was chasing down the wrong rabbit hole. All better now!